# Passing Amount from Button down to "Pay" Component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have a button in a component which hold the amount in {obj.amount},I want this amount to be passed down to PayView 'amount' param. Because "onPress" on the footer component, it takes me down to the payview component. How can I parse the amount down there.

```
 export default class FooterComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    //gas items
    const gas=[{
        title:"4kg",
        icon:"car",
        amount:'800',
    },
    {
        title:"12.5kg",
        icon:"car",
        amount:'4000',
    },
    {
        title:"26kg",
        icon:"car",
        amount:'8000',
    },
    ]
    return(
        <Footer style={{marginBottom:10,height:75}}>
            <FooterTab >
               {
                   gas.map((obj,index)=>{
                       return(
                           <Button key={index}  onPress={() => navigate('Landing')}>
                                <Icon size={37} name={obj.icon} />
                                <Text style={{fontSize:12}}>{obj.title}</Text>
                                <Text>{'\u20A6'}<Text style={{fontSize:13,fontWeight: 'bold',color:'#FFFFF'}}>{obj.amount}</Text></Text>
                            </Button>
                       )
                   })
               }
            </FooterTab>
        </Footer>
    )

}
}
```

I have this component

```
class  Landing  extends  React.Component { 

      render() {
          return (
              <PayView 
              buttonText=  "Pay Now"
              amount={120000}

             />
     );
     }
}
export default Landing;
```

Then Landing is then parse to Payment which then reference in StackNavigator

```
export default function Payment() {


  return (

    <Landing  />

  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is hoist the state up to the closest common component.

Create a state variable in the common component, pass a function down to **change** the state to the button component through props, which will call the function whenever the amount changes. Pass the **actual state** value down to the PayView component.

As the state is in the parent component, whenever the state changes (even if it's by the child Button component), React will trigger a render of the component tree from the parent down, updating the Button and PayView components with the new amount.

**EDIT**:

```
function Parent() {
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState();
  return (
    <Button onPay={setAmount} />
    <PayView amount={amount} />
  );
}

function Button({ onPay }) {
  return <button onClick={() => onPay(100)}>Pay!</button>;
}

function PayView({ amount }) {
  return (typeof amount === "number") ? (
    <div>Paying {amount}...</div>
  ) : (
    <div>Ready to pay</div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can I get an example, I'm quite new to react-native

Comment: This is one of the fundamental concepts of React, see how to lift state: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html, and how to keep state: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html.
There's a very basic example using the new functional component syntax and hooks instead of class components. The parent holds the state and will re-render and pass it down to the children.
I can't recommend enough that you try to get a better understanding before trying to implement something sensitive like a payment system.

Answer (score 0):

All i understand from the description of your problem is that you want to be able to push state up and access it to `<Landing />` component.

For such use case, you may need a common central state which can be accessed to all components whoever subscribe t that state.
In short, Redux,flux or ContextAPI.

but if you dont want to use any of those then you can make use of `useRef` hook . (if you are using React 16.8 + ) or `createRef` and then can access the state in `current` property of that reference.

check the console.
https://codepen.io/AshifZafar/pen/OJVbKzB?editors=1112